# Display custom post type and its custom category on content

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a custom post type for doctors and its custom categories,for example is pediatrician, and use builtin functions such as the content and the category for that post. The problem I'm facing is that I can't display the custom category of the custom post type. How can I achieve it?

custom category

[image: ..]

builtin function to display category

[image]

output

[image]

Comment: Please include formatted code as part of question instead of giving images.

Comment: Please post at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'yourtaxonomyhere');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_link = get_term_link($term, 'yourtaxonomyhere');
    if (is_wp_error($term_link))
        continue;
    echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
?>
```

Also see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/